# unable to deliver a pdf attachment to clients

Tags: email

On our website which is asp.net, we make a sale and an automated email is sent out to the client with an attached PDF invoice we create using a 3rd party app. We are having trouble getting these delivered successfully to some corporate clients. Yet we also send a copy of that same email to ourselves which we receive fine. We can then forward this on to the client and they do receive it no problems. So the original is not received but the forwarded mail is.
The webserver is a seperate IP address to our office Exchange server which sends the forwarded mail.

I have tried to find the difference between the 2 mails and it looked like a rich text issue, except that the mail is plain text or html!

The question is a little vague i know as i do not know where to look for the best. It seems to make no differenec which mail program is used, we tried MailEable and it was the same thing.
Mail is logged on the web server as leaving and that is the last we see of it. It doesnt bounce but it is definatley delivered to the client server, but doesnt reach the recipient. We used to track thru Message Labs and it would say it had reached the destination server ok. We do not use ML anymore until we find the issue, keeping it simple.
We have no issues sending to AOL, Hotmail and Yahoo etc.
It appears something in the email is upsetting server based spam software.
We havnt been able to get hold of any email logs from clients.

any suggestions?

Comment: this a response from one of the companies

Comment: There was a SMTP communication problem with the recipient's email server.  Please contact your system administrator.
            <earlyyearsvouchers.nh-serv.co.uk #5.5.0 smtp;552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation>

Comment: we used to use sbs2003 and are now on sbs 2008 The pdf generator is Aspose

Comment: i am checking the Aspose app. How can i check the format of the pdf to see if infringes the rfc? how do i check the lengths of unterminated lines?

Comment: have a look at the raw message body somehow (eg by sending it to a gmail address and select "show original" in the upper right corner of the message - that will show the raw message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://forums.msexchange.org/552_Requested_mail_action_aborted%3a_exceeded_storage_allocation/m_20583400/tm.htm) mentioning a reason not related to size issues

> The SMTP (internet mail protocol) RFC (An RFC is a document describing
>   the standards that make the Internet work.) explicitly states that the
>   length of a single unterminated line can be 1000 bytes, no larger.
>   Some SMTP servers violate this, and the Firebox (this is our firewall)
>   will drop the connection when the line length exceeds the configured
>   length, which defaults to 1000.

which might indicate your pdf generator and/or mail generator creates output that's not 100% standards compliant.  Might be a good point to check as it could explain why certain customer suffer fom this problem only.

Comment: hi, am checking both generators to see what they are doing

Comment: hi, how can i check if the mail and pdf generators are generating correctly? is there an analysis tool i could use perhaps?

Comment: A first check can be done visually, as I explained above - when looking at the raw message, do you see individual lines in the body (esp. in the pdf part) that are very long?

Comment: hi, i have the raw message now but it is too large to put in the edit or comments function! i will put it to view on our website at www.childcare-vouchers.net/raw.txt. i am not sure what i am looking at to diagnose the issue

Comment: Could this be the part that is causing the problem? it is to do with the pdf and there appears to be a lot of code included in the raw message-----=_NextPart_000_13D0_01CC63D6.F8F097D0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
        name="56955.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="56955.pdf"

Comment: Just checked, the longest line in your mail is just over 400 bytes, so that should not cause problems.  Another item to be checked I see however is that the MIME header for the html text part of the message announces Content-Type: text/html;charset="iso-8859-1" and
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit, and the meta Content-Type inside the mail announces content="text/html; charset=UTF-8".  Don't know if that cn trigger out certain security checks...

Comment: @dave the pdf part looks OK to me, it's announces as base64 encoded (and it is) and the lines are 77 bytes long, uniformely.  Conclusion, IMO the mail you send out seems correctly formatted (with 1 ? re the content type of the html part).

Comment: hi, the client had Watchdog/Firebox on his server and increasing the smtp proxy line length to 3000 enabled him to receive the mail. we are trying to reduce our line lengths too 73 to stop alll wrapping problems, which is what is happening here, with various programs. cheers

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem dave, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

> 552 Requested mail action aborted: exceeded storage allocation

This means there was a violation at the *client's* ("customer's") mail server.  The message exceeded a threshold/limit of some kind.  It's not clear if this is a *per-message limit* or if the *user's mailbox is just so full* that it cannot accept another message.

Either way, this is *mostly* out of your control.  Only thing you can do it try to keep your e-mail messages and attachments as small as possible.  If you can, compress (zip) any attachments before sending.

Comment: hi, it doesnt appear to be a mailbox size issue or message size. The whi=ole email and attachment is 37KB and we can send from the other IP to them no problems with bigger mail.

Comment: it is a line length issue we have identified

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Too bad the error message was so cryptic from their server.  Would have been better if it would have said something like `552 Requested mail action aborted: maximum line length exceeded`.